# Adding new line to NSCharacterSet

Tags: swift

I want to strip a string of all new lines and commas (and place it into an array), so I created this:

```
let results = text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ",\n"))
```

However, the newlines are still existing in my array (the commas are being removed). What's the correct way of adding newline to the NSCharacterSet? Or, how to add comma to NSCharacterSet.newLineCharacterSet.

Thanks.

Here is janky solution, but still looking for a more elegant one.

```
var results = text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ","))
text = results.joinWithSeparator(" ")
results = text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

(one-line) SOLUTION:

```
var results = text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " ,\u{000A}\u{000B}\u{000C}\u{000D}\u{0085}"))
```

Explanation is below.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with your first code snippet, it separates the string at all commas and newline (`\n`) characters. Please provide a sample input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: @MartinR I thought maybe there's not only "\n" but also "\r" in the text?

Comment: The text was pulled from a .txt file. I tried replicating the problem in a Playground but it works fine there where I create the strings specifically with \n line feeds. "\r" doesn't work either, although I assume the solution will be some similar to that.

Answer (score 5):

You can unite two NSCharacterSet by first using an NSMutableCharacterSet, for example:

```
let charset = NSMutableCharacterSet(charactersInString: ",")
charset.formUnionWithCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())

let results = text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charset)
```

Answer (score 0):

So MartinR brought to my attention that there are more line feeds than just "\n".

I looked at the values used in NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet and added them all, giving me:

```
var results = text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " ,\u{000A}\u{000B}\u{000C}\u{000D}\u{0085}"))
```

This got rid of all the whitespace, commas, and new lines. Interestingly - when I used all the newline values separately to see if I could figure out which newline was being used in my case, none of them worked. But when used all together, it strips my new lines.